# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hidden' of undefined(Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to draw a lineChart and the Errormessage,
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hidden' of undefined, occurs and I really don't know what am I missing.

1. Make canvas with id,'chart'
2. get the 'JsonObject' from DB using controller
   (In the JsonObject, I put the chart type, 'line', and also put the JsonArray, the data)
3. move the data from JsonArray to Array using function 'getArray' to remove the index
4. set the chart configuration and make a chart.

   ```
   function makeChart(year,month,name){
   var chart = $('#chart'); //
   var valueArray = new Array();

   $.ajax({
       dataType : 'json',
       url : '/individual/makeChart',
       data : {
           'year': year,
           'month': month,
           'name' : name
       },
       async : false,
       success : function(json) {
           valueArray = getArray(json);

           var config = {
                   type : json.type,
                   data : {
                       datasets : [{
                           borderColor : "#3e95cd",
                           data : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'],
                           label : 'region'
                       }, {
                           borderColor : "#c45850",
                           data : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'],
                           label : 'country'
                       }],
                   },
                   options:{
                       showLines:true,
                       legend:{
                           display:true,
                           labels:{
                               fontSize:15,
                               fontColor:"#000000",
                               fontStyle:"bold"
                           }
                       },
                       responsive : true,
                       scales : {
                           yAxes : [{
                               ticks : {
                                   beginAtZero : true,
                                   fontSize : 15,
                                   fontColor : "#000000",
                                   fontStyle : "bold"
                               }

                           }],
                           xAxes : [{
                               ticks : {
                                   fontSize : 15,
                                   fontColor : "#000000",
                                   fontStyle : "bold"
                               }
                           }]
                       }
                   }
           }

           new Chart(chart,config); // the problem occurs here!
       }
   });

     }

    function getArray(json){
      var a = new Array();
      a = json.Data[0];
      return a;
     }
   ```

Comment: Where are you using the property `hidden`?

Comment: are you waiting until the document is ready before running `makeChart`?